# How do I change the path while executing make file_defconfig Android kernel?

Tags: android-kernel

After the following lines:

```
export CROSS_COMPILE=/home/yourusername/NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-

make clean && make mrproper
```

**make maker.defconfig** gives me this error:

> Can't find default configuration "arch/x86/configs/filename_defconfig".

It is searching in **x86/configs/filename_defconfig** instead of **arm/configs/filename_defconfig**. How do I change the path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just missing an `export`:

```
export ARCH=arm //Or whatever architecture you're compiling for
export CROSS_COMPILE=/home/yourusername/NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-
make clean && make mrproper
```

Please be advised you're only cleaning the kernel build this way, to actually compile it replace the make command with these ones (you still need the exports):

```
make <target config file>
make -j<number of cores you wish to use for compilation>
```

You can also add the `export` lines directly to the make command like so:

```
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=/home/yourusername/NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- <make target>
```